# rescue 500 error without messing Airbrake up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, airbrake

I have Airbrake installed on my Rails app. However, I also want to perform some other actions when a 500 occurs. How do I rescue 500 errors without interfering with Airbrake?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way you can do this in your `ApplicationController`, you can put

```
unless Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local
  rescue_from Exception, with: :render_500
end
```

and later, a new `render_500` method

```
def render_500(ex)
  notify_airbrake(ex)
  # render your template/message
end
```

Comment: Cool. Had to do `unless Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local`, but otherwise works.

Comment: What version of Rails are you using? I'll happily update my answer to reflect this if it's current.

Comment: I'm using 3.2.9. I think the version I provided works for Rails 3 in general.